# Copy and paste PDF word results in garbage

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, copy-paste

I have PDF file for Korean language study. The file is copyable but when I paste it results in garbage as below. I've read old threads and tried methods but didn't succeed. I've uploaded the file [here](https://www.docdroid.net/h8Ih9ll/267066886-j6ivl-korean-grammar-in-use-intermediate-pdf-part3.pdf).

This is the full book [Korean Grammar in Use](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByWIFjKd7N_fTFh4VHhhVGZvelk/view) if anyone has problem with the link above.

Could anyone help me?

It does not have problem with English text in the same book:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have enough confidence in this to make it an answer, but it could be because the PDF doesn't actually have the text you're trying to copy in the first place and the reader is making it up with OCR or something.

Comment: Do you have Korean installed in your system? You may have other display language but you need Korean installed as well. Otherwise you won't have the required fonts.

Comment: @Stackstuck: There are both Korean and English in the same file. I don't have any problem with copy and paste English sentence. However, Korean results in garbage.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia: I can type Korean and display Korean in my computer. Does this mean I have the font?

Comment: I suppose you do but you can check.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia how can I check it? I type Korean almost every day on this computer recently. I also have Korean language added in language option.

Comment: *I also have Korean language added in language option* So you have and that's not the problem. My initial hypotheses is now falsified and I have no other to offer, sorry.

Comment: Are the Korean fonts properly embedded in the PDF?